# real closure of an archimedean field

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, model-theory, valuation-theory

my question is: Is an archimedean field dense in its real closure?
I know that in the non-archimedean case, this does not have to be true (e.g., rational fucntions).

Thanks!

Comment: I have a naive question which may be a mistake on my part. Aren't  Archimedian fields and their real closures just fields between $\Bbb Q$ and $\Bbb R$? And since it's the case that $\Bbb Q$ is dense in $\Bbb R$, $\Bbb Q$ (and hence your Archimedean field) would be dense in the closure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since Archimedean fields and their real closures are just fields between $\Bbb Q $ and $\Bbb R$, and the rationals are already dense in the reals, the rationals must also be dense in the real closure of your field. Thus certainly the original field is dense in its real closure.

Comment: So are you sure about that? In the comment you were kind of not sure...

Comment: Dear @cruvadom : I know with 100% certainty that Archimedian fields are subfields of $\Bbb R$, and I was *pretty darned sure* that a real closure of a subfield of $\Bbb R$ ought to lie in $\Bbb R$. The reason I sound like I'm doubting myself is that the answer seems so obvious. If there is some problem, I do hope someone lets me know so I can take action here. I have no idea where you got the question from, so I have no idea how to gauge its difficulty. If you've got a credible reason for me to doubt my line of thought, let me know.  Regards

Comment: The reason I'm asking is because you wrote "I have a naive question which may be a mistake on my part". I thank you for your help.

Comment: @cruvadom I understand :) It's just easy to second guess oneself when the answer seems obvious, so that's why a balked.